# How to merge to .htaccess files

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is for 404 error pages:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

This is for url rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
```

When i try to use them both it works but when i type in the url smth. like host/username it redirects to 404.php but this username exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply combine them together
i've tried it on index.php
and i got the index not 404 when i tried host/eli

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
```

also you should do in profile.php

```
if(user_not_exists($_GET['username'])){
require_once '404.php'
}
```